# How to get nested array item where object property id is "random" and change the name property

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash, javascript-objects

I have a nested array of objects. How to get nested array item where object property id is "random" and set name to "you won it"
The structure looks like this:

```
[
{
itemsBundle [
{
id: 'selection'
name: 'failed'
}
{
id: 'random'
name:'win'
}
]
basketId: 'item'
basketName
tags[{}{}]
}
{}
{}
]
```

I need somehow get the object inside the main array where nested itemsBundle array of objects containes object with id 'random' and then for that itemBundle's single object where id is 'random' set name from win to you won it. I thought about using nested map() with filter() or nested loops but not sure which option will be the best and how can this results be achieved with less complicated way. The only 3rd party library that I am using is lodash.

Comment: This is not valid syntax.

Comment: @Taplar It's vue js so I just reproduced it based on vue dev tools output. The problem is not syntax but the way to solve the name changing based on id for a nested object inside nested array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example with flatMap and find. BUT it is mutating the main content, you have to clone deep you list first.
Improve your question next time :)

```js
const aa = [
  {
    itemsBundle: [
      {
        id: "selection",
        name: "failed"
      },
      {
        id: "random",
        name: "win"
      }
    ],
    basketId: "item",
    basketName: "",
    tags: [{}, {}]
  },
  {},
  {}
];

const items = aa.flatMap(a => a.itemsBundle || [])
const itemFound = items.find(item => item.id === 'random')
itemFound.name = 'you win'

console.log(aa[0].itemsBundle[1])
```

Comment: I think it can be mutated it's a vuejs data{}